# Callbacks and passing variables to second function

Tags: javascript, callback, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a map that needs a bunch of data. The data function loads the data then the map function executes with the data previously loaded. This is the code that did that and it worked fine:

```
var states;
var counties;

function loadData() {
  function getStates() {
    return fetch(states.json).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
      });
    }

  getStates().then(function(response) {
    states = response;
    console.log(states);
    });

  function getCounties() {
    return fetch(counties.json).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
      });
    }

  getCounties().then(function(response) {
    counties = response;
    console.log(counties);
    });
}

function loadMaps() {

  /*------map function here that uses the counties,
          and states variables to build the map---------*/

  }

loadData();
loadMaps();
```

The problem started when I needed a much larger data file `tracts`. I used a callback function to ensure that `loadData` would finish before `loadMaps` executed. This is the code:

```
var states;
var counties;
var tracts;

function loadData(subject, callback) {
  function getTracts() {
    return fetch(tracts.json).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
      });
    }
  getTracts().then(function(response) {
    tracts = response;
    console.log(tracts);

    function getCounties() {
      return fetch(counties.json).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
        });
      }

    getCounties().then(function(response) {
    counties = response;
    console.log(counties);

      function getStates() {
        return fetch(states.json).then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
          });
        }

      getStates().then(function(response) {
        states = response;
        console.log(states);

      callback(tracts, counties, states);
      console.log(`Loading year ${year} map.`);

      }); //------------getStates
    }); //-----------getCounties
  }); //----------getTracts
} //---------loadData

function loadMaps() {

  /*------map function here that uses the tracts, counties,
          and states variables to build the map---------*/

  }

loadData("2018", function() {
  loadMaps();
  });
```

The data loads but then the map function doesn't execute. No errors show up in the console and the console shows that all the data is loaded. I suspect that it has to do with the multiple variables `tracts, counties, states` that I'm passing to `loadMaps` but I can't figure out how to fix it. I tried it with just one variable passed to `loadMaps` and `loadMaps` still didn't execute. If I comment out `loadData`, `loadMaps` runs (though with a bunch of errors because `states`, `counties`, and `tracts` are empty). I'm new to learning about callbacks and have been trying to get this to work for nearly a week. Are the variables not being passed to `loadMaps`? And why wouldn't `loadMaps` execute anyway and just show that the data are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code. Your nested structure was somehow too complicated and error prone. Now the code executes entirely. The only problem I have is, that I mocked the `fetch()` function and do not get a valid response-object. Thus I had to comment out the `xyz = response.json()` lines. As the code got stuck there.

Have a look if this helps you.

```
var states = {};
var counties = {};
var tracts = {};

function loadData(subject, callback) {
  console.log('loadData: ', subject);

  getTracts(); // start    

  function getTracts() {
    console.log('getTracts()');

    fetch(tracts.json).then(function(response) {
          console.log('tracts: ', response);
          // tracts = response.json();

          // next
          getCounties();
      });
  }

  function getCounties() {
    console.log('getCounties()');
    fetch(counties.json).then(function(response) {
          console.log('counties: ', response);
          // counties = response.json();

          // next
          getStates();
      });
  }

  function getStates() {
    console.log('getStates()');
    fetch(states.json).then(function(response) {
          console.log('states: ', response);
          // states = response.json();

          // finish
          callback(tracts, counties, states);
      });
  }
} //---------loadData

function fetch() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve({content: 'foo'}); });
}

function loadMaps() {

    console.log('inside map');
    console.log('tracts inside map: ', tracts);
    console.log('counties inside map: ', counties);
    console.log('states inside map: ', states);

  }

loadData("2018", function() {
  loadMaps();
});
```

Comment: I changed the nesting and now `loadMaps` executes. But the callbacks aren't getting passed through because I'm getting errors from the variables in `loadMaps` that depend on `states`, `counties`, and `tracts`. I think the nesting was maybe only one part of the problem.

Comment: Can you show what the content of the variables is and what the error looks like?

Comment: It's a mapbox error: "The layer '2010srt' does not exist in the map's style and cannot be queried for features." `loadMaps` uses `states` to build layer `2010srt`. If it doesn't have the data from `states` then it can't build the layer. The content is geodata (lat/long, place names, etc.) in json format, e.g. [{"GISJOIN": "G0100010020100",
   "YEAR": 2010,
   "REGIONA": 3,
   "DIVISIONA": 6,
   "STATE": "Alabama",
   "STATEA": 1,
   "COUNTY": "Autauga County"}]

Comment: Solved it. I had to load the MapBox basemap first before `loadMaps` could access the variables passed from `loadData`.